# Error message - view server state permission was denied - when connecting to SQL Server 2014 using SQL Server 2012 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, ssms, connectivity

When right-clicking on a table and selecting "select top 1000 rows", I get this error:

[image]

Is there any workaround, other than the obvious upgrade to SQL Server 2014?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just for reference, this problem seems to be related to this Connect bug:

[Cannot view properties of database when using db owner account](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/791630/cannot-view-properties-of-database-when-using-db-owner-account) - by Jimmy Rudley

> Posted by Microsoft on 7/9/2013 at 2:47 PM
>   [...] We have corrected this for the next version of SQL 14.
>   Walter A Jokiel, Program Manager, SQL Server

I have the same problem with SQL Server 2012 Management Studio 2012.

If anyone finds themselves stuck with this problem, try to update SQL Server Management Studio. This way, you don't need to grant the permission `VIEW SERVER STATE` to the user.

Using SQL Server Management Studio 2014 (12.0.4213.0) now, and the problem seems to be gone.

Answer (score 15):

The least intrusive way to get this working is to either use the following command or have the DBA issue this command for you:

```
use master
go
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO <user_name>
```

Comment: maybe use `[]` around the user_name

Answer (score 1):

You will get this error message if the user was granted `SELECT` on single tables.
You will not run into this problem when user is member of `db_datareader`.

I don't like the idea of granting `VIEW SERVER STATE` to standard users.

This bug still exists in SSMS 17.1

Comment: I cannot confirm that. Right now I am a member of `db_datareader` on one such 2012 server, and getting this error. No table level permissions have been granted.